# Change Search Highlight Color In Less

Tags: linux, colors, less, pager, termcap

I am a bit lost here on customizing the search/find highlight color or font format if you will. I understand that using `LESS_TERMCAP_*` we can alter the font format of less display. Full capabilities are [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/termcap).

But I couldn't get how to change the search highlight! I want to add background color and change fore color to make them different from the standard output colors. Negating the standard output is preferred.

Also, one more question. A parameter with special characters (like `@0`), how can we write their `LESS_TERMCAP_` variable?

It's getting really annoying not being able to even guess which one to use to change the colors! Thanks in advance for shedding some light on the matter.

Comment: It is `LESS_TERMCAP_so`.

Comment: Working! Thanks. But how can I able to tell without asking every time I want to know which key to use?

Comment: It is not well documented, you need to read sources, or just experiment a bit. There are only 4 capabilities supported in less: `_so`(standout), `_mb`(blinking), `_md`(bold) and `_us`(underline), so not much to experiment with.

Answer (score 4):

There is a list of different termcaps global variables that are read by `less`; the relevant ones are found in the code as:

```
tmodes("so", "se", &sc_s_in, &sc_s_out, "", "", &sp);
tmodes("us", "ue", &sc_u_in, &sc_u_out, sc_s_in, sc_s_out, &sp);
tmodes("md", "me", &sc_b_in, &sc_b_out, sc_s_in, sc_s_out, &sp);
tmodes("mb", "me", &sc_bl_in, &sc_bl_out, sc_s_in, sc_s_out, &sp);
```

The `tmodes` function prefixes its first two arguments with `LESS_TERMCAP_` and uses the value of the env variable with that name for, as described by user jimmij:

- `so` standout, `se` exit standout,
- `us` underline, `ue` exit underline,
- `md` bold, `me` exit underline,
- `mb` blinking, `me` exit blinking (and underline).

You can have your matches appearing in red using:

```
$ export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(echo -e '\e[1;91m')
$ export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(echo -e '\e[0m')
```

See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) for more on ANSI escape sequences (including background coloring, bold, ...).

It's worth noting that `less` reads much more `LESS_TERMCAP_*` variables than just these (for keys, for instance).

Comment: what should I do for changing backgorund highlight color?

Comment: @alper: This is "standout" in the color code.  Refer to the Wikipedia page quoted in the answer to see how to use ANSI escape sequences for background color.